# R Markdown: Citation parsing

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I am trying to typeset citations in my R Markdown document, and it appears that the citations are not parsed correctly in some cases, specifically, when citations appear with a `:`, such as `[@ref1]:` and some text following it.

Here is an MWE:

```
---
title: Citations Parsing
references:
- id: fenner2012a
  title: One-click science marketing
  author:
  - family: Fenner
    given: Martin
  container-title: Nature Materials
  volume: 11
  URL: 'http://dx.doi.org/10.1038/nmat3283'
  DOI: 10.1038/nmat3283
  issue: 4
  publisher: Nature Publishing Group
  page: 261-263
  type: article-journal
  issued:
    year: 2012
    month: 3
---

1. [@fenner2012a]: Here is some text. **This does not work.**
2. [@fenner2012a]:
3. [@fenner2012a] : Here is some text. **This works.**
```

I am on the latest version of `rmarkdown` from CRAN (0.8.1). Note that in the example above, #2 works as well. It is when you chase up the `:` with text, that the citation stops rendering.

### Edit:

This could very well be a `knitr` problem as well. I am on the latest version of knitr from CRAN (1.11).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like `knitr` is trying to parse the whole citation, including the semicolon. To stop it, use a `\` to escape the colon:

```
[@fenner2012a]\: Here is some text. **This works now.**
```

Comment: Unexpected for sure, not sure I'd call it a bug though